# Qt write styled xml to pdf

Tags: c++, css, xml, qt, pdf

I have an Qt project, XML template and CSS style. I want to apply CSS to my XML file and write result to the PDF file using Qt libs. Can anyone give some examples or links? Also links to the official documentation is nice, because I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Take a look at [Syntax Highlighter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html) example and [QPrinter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QPrinter.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply prajmus!
Syntax Highlighter example is not my case. I think I can parse dom document and stylings on my own, but is there any ways to print QDomDocument using QPrinter? I didn't find any methods in QtDocs

Comment: How can I, for example, convert styled xml to QTextDocument and then use built-in print function? Just copy some plain text is fine, but I don't know if styles will be saved